# 3 way calculation

Tags: c#

I have a data object with three fields, A, B and C. The problem is that the user can set any of them because:

A * B = C

So if a user starts off by setting A & B, C will be calculated.  but then if a user set C, A gets recalculated, so there is an implicit anchoring that is happening based off the last field that the user set.

i want to avoid a solution with a lot of flag member variables.  Any best practices on how i can code this class up without having a lot of stuff  like this below

```
public class Object
{
     private double _A;
     private double _B;
     private double _C;

     private bool _enteredA;
     private bool _enteredB;
     private bool _enteredC;

public double A
{
get
    {
     if (_enteredC)
     {
          return _C / _B;
     }
     else
     {
        return _A;
     }
  }
}
```

should the logic of setting A, B, and C always be on the "get" or the "set".

Is there any cleaner way to doing this?

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? What if I say C = 4.3 /1.9; ? What is your logic for that? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: i dont understand your questions.  i added some member variables to hpefully make it clearer

Comment: Since A * B = C is initially valid when the object is instantiated with all its members set to 0, is it fair to assume that you're not concerned with tracking which fields are set by the user versus which fields still have their initial values?

Comment: @Ates, @ak states "A & B, C will be calculated. but then if a user set C, A gets recalculated". This contradicts your assumption. The solution needs to track the order of being set.

Comment: @ak states "A & B, C will be calculated. but then if a user set C, A gets recalculated". -- why not B?  Can you tell us the use case for this?  There is probably a simpler way of handling this than lumping all the three variables in one object.

Comment: @moogs: I expect that the scenario is that the calculation is complex (not just a multiply) and the user sets an input to see the effect on the output and then adjusts the output to see the effect on the (last) input.  The user can then iterate to an acceptable solution.  I could be way off here!

Comment: @ak maybe you could be more explicit re: 'implicit anchoring' because it seems many people are getting hung up on this. How this is interpreted is a major requirement to the correct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your rules are:

```
A = C / B
B = C / A
C = A * B
```

What you'd need to do is remember the last **two** fields that the user entered, and from that, calculate the third. Therefore if they entered A and then B, then you calculate C. If they then change C, then recalculate A, and so on.

If you want to code it without using boolean flags, there's a couple of different ways you could do that. A queue, or just a simple array/map would work:

```
editOrder = {A : 0, B : 0, C : 0 }  // (or just use 0, 1, 2)
editCount = 0;

every time any field is edited :
    editCount = editCount + 1
    editOrder[field] = editCount
    if two fields have an editOrder > 0
        recalculate the field with the lowest editOrder
```

Example usage:

```
Field changed    editOrder        recalculate field
    A            1,0,0            -
    A            2,0,0            -
    B            2,3,0            C
    C            2,3,4            A
    C            2,3,5            A
    B            2,6,5            A
    A            7,6,5            C
```

Comment: this is correct. . . but i want the best way to code this without all these boolean flags hanging around

Comment: you are going to need those flags because you need to keep track of which fields are set in which order.

Answer (score 3):

You state that your properties have the relationship "A * B = C".  So, your class should express this.  A and B are independent variables, so they have simple setters and getters that merely get and set a filed.  C is a Dependant variable and so it should only have a getter and perform the calculation based on A and B:

```
class Foo
{
    private double m_a;
    public double A
    {
        get { return m_a; }
        set { m_a = value; }
    }

    private double m_b;
    public double B
    {
        get { return m_b; }
        set { m_b = value; }
    }

    public double C
    {
        get { return A * B; }
    }
}
```

An editor can be written that allows A and B to edited trivially.  It can also allow the user to edit C if (and only if) the user has edited A or B already.  The view would store some state to indicate which (if any) field was last edited and can therefore apply the appropriate change to A or B when the conceptual C is edited.

Now, if the View is unaware of the calculation of C, you can add methods to the Foo class to "SetAGivenC()" and "SetBGivenC()":

```
class Foo
{
    ... as above ...

    public void SetAGivenC( double newC )
    {
        A = newC/B;
    }

    public void SetBGivenC( double newC )
    {
        B = newC/A;
    }
}
```

Now your GUI just calls one of these methods when "C" is edited.

I am confused as to what "last field that the user set" means.  Imagine that there are two editors up on the screen (both bound to the same Foo instance) and the user edits A in the first editor, then B in the second, then C in the first.  What gets adjusted when C is set? A or B?  If you can answer this question, you will know which class should track the "last field that the user set" - should it be the model or the view?  I expect that A would be adjusted in this case and the view tracks the last edited field.  But that's an issue for another day!

Edit:

Jeepers - I even stuffed up my own pathological case!

I'll try that last paragraph again:

I am confused as to what "last field that the user set" means.  Imagine that there are two editors up on the screen (both bound to the same Foo instance) and the user edits A then B in the first editor, the user then edits B then A in the second, the user then edits C in the first.  What gets adjusted when C is set? A or B?  If you can answer this question, you will know which class should track the "last field that the user set" - should it be the model or the view?  I expect that A would be adjusted in this case and the view tracks the last edited field.  But that's an issue for another day!

Comment: looking forward to your answer, but just want to quickly point out that the question is asking to solve for the missing variable based on unknown input. "setting A & B, C will be calculated. but then if a user set C, A gets recalculated"

Comment: @Robert: Hope you like the answer.  I have taken a different spin on the question, and it may or may not be a valid interpretation.

Comment: I read it as: Set A, Set B (AB) => C calculated. Set C => input A discarded (BC) and A calculated. Set B, old  B discarded (CB) => A is calculated. The real equation is immaterial. It's the strategy to solve for the missing variable without using loads of booleans.

Comment: I disagree - from the description there is a dependant variable C calculated from the independant variables A and B.  It should be modeled this way.  The idea of the "implicit anchoring" sounds merely like the way the app designer wants the user to interact with the class.  'tis a UI issue only.

Comment: @Robert: what do you think should happen with the "tow editors, one model" scenario I mentioned?

Comment: Nah I think you read in the simultaneous editing scenario. The dependent variable is whatever variable is not defined. It's just using basic algebraic manipulations e.g. z = x + y <=> x = z - y <=> y = z - x

Comment: Thinking of a variable as both free and dependent is asking for trouble - or confusion and complication at least.  Surely modeling it as I have, where C = A * B is sufficient and the concept of "implicit anchoring" is a concern of a higher layer in the system.

Comment: I agree with Daniel, maintaining a definite distinction between free and calculated state is crucial. I could imagine an editor for A,B that lets the user type a C value, shows the underlying values of A and B, and has a radio button to indicate whether A or B should be modified to get required C.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I agree that a variables is either free or calculated, but the free versus calculated appears to be decided at runtime, not compile time. @Daniels example fixes C as always being the dependent var and forces clients (UI) to know this and call special methods.

Comment: @Robert:  I have not misunderstood you.  I believe the free versus calculated nature of the vars should be set at compile time.  Your solution makes dependent vars look like free vars.  How does the client know that setting, say, C will affect, say, A?  How is this side effect expressed in the API?

Comment: I read it as a goal-seeking problem. Just goes to show you how inaccurate requirements can lead to different interpretations of what's important.

Comment: If the UI is already smart enough to call SetAGivenB/C, why bother storing a,b,c? Simplify by having only CalculateCGivenAB() CalculateAGivenBC() and CalculateBGivenAC()

Comment: @Robert: I agree that the requirements as stated are too slack, so we may never know what was actually required.  Regarding the CalcXGivenYZ() methods, there are many way to model this class, but properties are useful (or required), so I wouldn't abandon them!  Eg, needed for WFP databinding.

Answer (score 0):

create a private method to do the following calculation

```
private void calculateFields(){
  if (_b != INIT_VALUE && _c != INIT_VALUE)
     _a =  _c / _b;
  if (_a != INIT_VALUE && _c != INIT_VALUE)
     _b = _c / _a;
  if (_a != INIT_VALUE && _b != INIT_VALUE)
     _c = _a * _b;
}

public double A
{
get{
        return _a;
  }
set{
   _a = value;
   calculateFields();
}
}
```

Do the same for property B and C.

Comment: Don't think this works since I'm pretty sure he wants to be able to have it compute on the fly indefinitely.

Comment: This also doesn't work according to "setting A & B, C will be calculated. but then if a user set C, A gets recalculated"

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

You could create an adapter to handle the logic you're describing. You'd be moving the complexity out of this class and into another though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this (thanks to [nickf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445658/3-way-calculation#445690) for taking the trouble to sovle the equation for each value):

```
class Foo
{
    // Mark these as obsolete so that
    // you don't use them by mistake
    // in the class.
    [Obsolete]
    private double _a;
    [Obsolete]
    private double _b;
    [Obsolete]
    private double _c;

    #pragma warning disable 0612
    public double A
    {
        get
        {
            return _a;
        }
        set
        {
            _a = value;
            // You may want to change
            // this to simply _a.
            _b = _c / (_a == 0 ? 1 : _a);
            _c = _a * _b;
        }
    }

    public double B
    {
        get
        {
            return _b;
        }
        set
        {
            _b = value;
            _a = _c / (_b == 0 ? 1 : _b);
            _c = _a * _b;
        }
    }

    public double C
    {
        get
        {
            return _c;
        }
        set
        {
            _c = value;
            _a = _c / (_b == 0 ? 1 : _b);
            _b = _c / (_a == 0 ? 1 : _a);
        }
    }
    #pragma warning restore 0612
}
```

Comment: It's not correct though. If you set Set A, you can not then calculate B from A,C and then C from B,A. The class needs to receive any 2 variables and compute the missing one. Calculation can occur if and only if 2 different variables were set.

Comment: The hint of why it won't work is that "setting A & B, C will be calculated. but then if a user set C, A gets recalculated"

Comment: Should we really rely on floating point comparison like this?

Comment: @Robert, which means when all three have been calculated, if you change one the other remain 'sane'. I admit, it is questionable if two of them have not been set. Maybe a few ctors? @Daniel, not too sure what you mean.

Comment: @Jonathan, please see my reply below as a comment on your calculation method.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan

My point about errors in your method of calculations is as follows:

In the code you wrote, the following sequence of events occurs.

```
given a valid state at some point of time.
[a = 1, b = 3, c = 3]
```

call your setter with b = 4, which by your code will then calculate a and c:

```
1. first sets b          b = 4
2. first calculates a    a = c / b =  3  / 4  =  3/4
3. then calculates  c    c = a * b = 3/4 * 4  =  3
```

the final tuple is

```
[a = 3/4, b = 4, c = 3]
```

In essence, for your class (as currently written)

```
setting b alters a  ->  leaves c unaffected.
setting c alters a  ->  leaves b unaffected.
setting a alters b  ->  leaves c unaffected
```

Calculation (3) is useless because if `A` was already derived from `C` and `B`, re-deriving `C` from `A` and `B` will not change the value of `C`, *ever*.

Setting `A` or `B` should calculate `C`, and there is a special case where setting `C` calculates `A` or `B` without using a boolean to know which one. (the question as posted)